# Using Scanner to read the

Tags: java, while-loop, switch-statement, java.util.scanner, bluej

When I want to read the name of the user using the scanner and then assging the value of the name in a string and after that invoking the method getName and give it an argument of the name to print out my name is ...., my code just crash and does not work I tried to figure out the problem but I could not

```
 public void getName(String name)
   {
       String s = "your name is: "+name   ;
   }
    public void userInput()
    {
        print();
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        String read = s.nextLine();
        String op = read;
        while(!read.equals("Exit"))
        {  
            switch (op){
                case "a" :
                System.out.println("type your name:");
                read = s.nextLine();
                getName(read);
                print();
                read = s.nextLine();
                op = read;
                break;
                case"b" :
                System.out.println("by");
                print();
                read = s.nextLine();
                op = read;
                break;
            }

        }
    }

    public void print()
    {
        System.out.println("press a");
        System.out.println("press b");
    }
```

Comment: Where does it crash? What error does it give?

Comment: Code doesn't `just crash`.  What kind of error are you getting?

Comment: when i invoke the method userInput() it works fine and when I type a it will ask me to write my name but after when it send the String name to the method getName it enters in a loop and it does not break out

Comment: It does not print out the name when invoking the method getName inside  the first case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make your while condition false, add a `default` statement in the switch:

```
    while (!read.equals("Exit")) {
        switch (op) {
        case "a":
            System.out.println("type your name:");
            read = s.nextLine();
            getName(read);
            print();
            read = s.nextLine();
            op = read;
            break;
        case "b":
            System.out.println("by");
            print();
            read = s.nextLine();
            op = read;
            break;
        default: // Add this to finish loop when you type "Exit"
            read = s.nextLine();
        }

    }
```

**Edit**

Your call to method getName(read) is not useful, try one of the following:

**1.** You could make `getName()` return a String and store it in your `userInput()` to use it later. By the way, getSomething() methods usually are used to return something.

```
public static String getName(String name) {
    String s = "Your name is: " + name;
    return s;
}
```

And this in `userInput()` method:

```
String name = getName(read);
```

**2.** Or print something in the `void getName(String name)` method:

```
System.out.println("Your name is: " + name);
```

And call `getName(read)` in the `userInput()` method:

```
getName(read);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't do anything useful in `getName`. My guess is that you want to print the name, like this:

```
public void getName(String name) // should rename this method 'printName'
{
    System.out.println("your name is: "+name);
}
```

Comment: It does not print out the name when invoking the method getName inside  the first case, this is what I asked for

Comment: In that case, I hope my example code will help you.